# Magento 2: Use Blog as seperate domain

Tags: magento2.3.3, blog

I'm using the Magefan Blog extension https://magefan.com/magento2-blog-extension

It displays blog with the URL https://www.example.com/blog

How can I use a Blog as a separate domain like https://blog.example.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use Magento 2 default concept of URL rewrites.

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/url-rewrite-custom.html

Here is the full specification of it. It will helps you.

Thanks